# How to solve an instantiate the map fragment error?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, onclick

```
 public class OpenMapforLocating extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapClickListener,OnMapLongClickListener,OnMarkerDragListener {

public GoogleMap myMap;

 Location myLocation;


 LatLng currentlatlon;

 String currentLocaiton;

 final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;

 boolean markerClicked;
 PolygonOptions polygonOptions;
 Polygon polygon;

 Button btn_selected;
 EditText txt_selectedLocaiton;
 String SelectioType;
 SharedPreferences prefrences;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "STPL_BOOKING_DETAILS";

     SharedPreferences prefrencesFaviourtes;
        public static final String PREFS_FAV = "STPL_BOOKING_FAVIOURTE_LIST";


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.openmapview);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    SelectioType = extras.getString("SelectionType");
    Log.d("SelectionActivity", "selection Type"+SelectioType);


    txt_selectedLocaiton =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editlocation);



    btn_selected =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_selectedLocation);


    btn_selected.setOnClickListener(onclickListner);
    android.app.FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment myMapFragment 
     = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
    myMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    markerClicked = false;


    LatLng myPoint= new LatLng(gpsdataElements.latitude, gpsdataElements.logitude);
    Log.d("OpenMapFOrLocation",gpsdataElements.latitude+"  "+gpsdataElements.logitude);
    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("mylocation").position(myPoint).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)).draggable(true));
    myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPoint, 15));
    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);



    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onDestroy()
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onPause()
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onRestart()
 */
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
}

private OnClickListener onclickListner = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_selectedLocation:

            prefrences= getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefrences.edit(); 

            if(SelectioType.contains("FromAddress"))
            {
                Constants.pickupLat=currentlatlon.latitude;
                Constants.pickupLon=currentlatlon.longitude;
                editor.putString("PickupLocation",txt_selectedLocaiton.getText().toString());
            }
            else if(SelectioType.contains("ToAddress"))
            {
                Constants.dropLat=currentlatlon.latitude;
                Constants.droplon=currentlatlon.longitude;
                editor.putString("DropLocation",txt_selectedLocaiton.getText().toString());
            }
            editor.commit();
            finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {

  super.onResume();

  int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

  if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
//     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
//       "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
//       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else{
   GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
  }

 }
@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myMap.clear();

    currentlatlon =point;
    //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), point.latitude +" "+point.longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      markerClicked = false;
      Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
      StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

        //
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude, 1);


            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                txt_selectedLocaiton.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
                currentLocaiton=strReturnedAddress.toString();
            }
            else{
                txt_selectedLocaiton.setText("No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            txt_selectedLocaiton.setText("Canont get Address!");
        }



        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("mylocation").position(point).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)).draggable(true));
        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 15));
        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);


}
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.mapmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
     * Identify single menu item by it's id
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_myfaviourts:
            // Single menu item is selected do something
            // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
            prefrencesFaviourtes= getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FAV, 0);
            String oldFaviouteLoc=prefrencesFaviourtes.getString("myFaviourteLocation", "");
            prefrencesFaviourtes= getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FAV, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor favEditor = prefrencesFaviourtes.edit();
            favEditor.putString("myFaviourteLocation", oldFaviouteLoc+"!"+currentLocaiton+"$"+currentlatlon.latitude+"$"+currentlatlon.longitude+"!");
            favEditor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(OpenMapforLocating.this, "New Favioute saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_enableTraffic:
            Toast.makeText(OpenMapforLocating.this, "Save is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

openmapview.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editlocation"
    android:background="@color/Gray"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:hint="select location"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_selectedLocation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editlocation"
     />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_below="@+id/map"
    >

</LinearLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_selectedLocation"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext1"
android:text="ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat

```
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stpl.fasttrackbooking/com.stpl.fasttrackbooking.OpenMapforLocating}:  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.stpl.fasttrackbooking.OpenMapforLocating.onCreate(OpenMapforLocating.java:88)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  ... 11 more
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  ... 20 more
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.stpl.fasttrackbooking-1.apk]
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
08-23 15:08:49.330: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
```

This code works well in large and medium screen. I was try to modify this code to work in small screen. so that i created layout-small folder under res and ran this code. When click on the "place using map" option then the above error was occurred. I don't know which part of the code causes this kind of error. Where can i do the changes in the code.Help me friends.

Comment: According stack trace `google-play-services` missed in classpath.

Comment: ya i checked. Google play services added and shown in green tick mark. google-play-service was added.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA (Android Studio)?

Comment: Did you check this: [Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in Google Map V2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572020/error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-android-gms-maps-mapfragment)?

Comment: ya checked and set up done accordingly. But still error.

Comment: Post your xml file here...

Comment: @Piyush Gupta posted.. help me.

Answer (score 1):

In OnCreate you can get an error.

```
myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
```

check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909917/in-google-maps-v2-fragment-getmap-returns-null)

And after getMap. Check your map and only the do something with it: setting markers etc.

And check your layout at line 14:

`Caused by: android.view.InflateException: **Binary XML file line #14**: Error inflating class fragment`

EDIT

try to edit your fragment like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

     />
```

Comment: i will check @Volodymyr

Comment: same error my friend. I don't know how to solve this issue. #14 line error inflating class fragment. i don't know what was the problem in this part.