# Google map is null

Tags: android, google-maps

I can build an instance of Google Map and view the map but I can't getMap(), it's always null:

```
mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
                    // always null, why?
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: replacing Fragment is asynchronous, so this fragment could event not be already placed on your layout, so making getMap gives you null.
You should replace/add your mapFragment and request for map with getMap method after this mapFragment transaction ended

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14909970/1051804 answer

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> This works pretty well for me ...
> It seems like it's the default background (which is black) of SurfaceView which is causing this bug .
> ```

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment() {
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
  setMapTransparent((ViewGroup) view);
  return view;
 };

 private void setMapTransparent(ViewGroup group) {
  int childCount = group.getChildCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
   View child = group.getChildAt(i);
   if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
    setMapTransparent((ViewGroup) child);
   } else if (child instanceof SurfaceView) {
    child.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
   }
  }
 }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Map will be available in the onActivityCreated() when created programmatically. so, try like this:

```
mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

           if (mMap == null) {
                mMap = this.getMap();

                //other code
        }
    };
```

Check here: [How do I know the map is ready to get used when using the SupportMapFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047257/how-do-i-know-the-map-is-ready-to-get-used-when-using-the-supportmapfragment)