# Google map throwing null pointer exception

Tags: android, google-maps

hi i m creating a google map with marker and atatic longtitude and latitudes. but when i am running the project it is getting GoogleMap map as null. I have posted the code below.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
         Log.e("map",""+map);
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.staticgooglemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCIBfnWMI4FblFgD323o4IFaLLgfURUJO4" />

          <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" 
        />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
09-05 09:45:33.478: W/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-05 09:45:33.498: W/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-05 09:45:33.498: W/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-05 09:45:33.538: W/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-05 09:45:33.538: W/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-05 09:45:33.548: E/dalvikvm(5060): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b
09-05 09:45:33.578: W/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 139 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
09-05 09:45:33.578: D/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0008
09-05 09:45:33.578: E/dalvikvm(5060): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b
09-05 09:45:33.578: W/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 139 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
09-05 09:45:33.578: D/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000c
09-05 09:45:33.608: W/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-05 09:45:33.648: W/dalvikvm(5060): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-05 09:45:33.798: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:33.888: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:33.948: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:33.998: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:34.038: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:34.118: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:34.158: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:34.188: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:34.198: D/dalvikvm(5060): GC_CONCURRENT freed 192K, 10% free 2644K/2936K, paused 24ms+3ms, total 162ms
09-05 09:45:34.198: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:34.238: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:34.258: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5060): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 3136130
09-05 09:45:34.258: E/map(5060): null
09-05 09:45:34.258: D/AndroidRuntime(5060): Shutting down VM
09-05 09:45:34.268: W/dalvikvm(5060): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.staticgooglemap/com.example.staticgooglemap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at com.example.staticgooglemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-05 09:45:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(5060):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Logcat output of crash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [in google maps V2 ... fragment.getMap() returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909917/in-google-maps-v2-fragment-getmap-returns-null)

Comment: Please post the logcat exception !

Comment: Whats line MainActivity.java:31?

Comment: @Dhruti: Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
    .title("Hamburg")); becz map is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first by this.

```
   if(map !=null){
   Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(KIEL)
            .title("Kiel")
            .snippet("Kiel is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

    }
```

Also add this line in ur manifest file.

```
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Comment: same problem is still there..map is still null

Comment: First time when ur map load for sometimes it will be null. Also try to change your target SDK to 19

Comment: You'r always wel come. Glad to help you!