# Android - executePendingTransactions cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: java, android, static, transactions, execution

I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14917118/4351949) answer that

> If you want to immediately executing any such pending operations, you can call this function (only from the main thread) to do so.

But, if I call it from the static main thread, I get an error that says executePendingTransactions() is non-static and cannot be referenced from static context.

How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: You're probably trying to call this method on FragmentTransaction class which won't work since it's not a static method. You should call it on an instance of FragmentTransaction. Posting the code will help to figure out the problem.

Comment: @Egor, I do `FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();`, and FragmentManager cannot be initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`executePendingTransactions()` is a regular non-static method on `FragmentManager`. You need an *instance* of `FragmentManager`, such as by calling `getFragmentManager()` (or `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you are using the fragments backport) on your `Activity` or `Fragment`.