# Restoring MapView's state on rotate and on back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, fragment-lifecycle

**Background**

I have a larger application in which I had/have several problems with new Google Maps API. I tried to describe it [in a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171619/markers-disapearing-from-mapview-v2-in-fragment-on-back) but since it seems too complex I decided to start a new project, as simple as possible and try to reproduce problems. So here it is.

**The situation**

I'm using `Fragments` and want to put `MapView` inside. I don't want to use `MapFragment`. The sample project I prepared may be not very beautiful but I tried to make it as simple as possible and it had to contain some elements (again simplified) from the original app.
I have one `Activity` and my custom `Fragment` with `MapView` in it, added programatically. The `Map` contains some points/`Markers`. After clicking on a `Marker` the `InfoWindow` is shown and clicking on it causes next `Fragment` being shown (with `replace()` function) in content.

**The problems**

There are two issues I have:

1. When the `Map` with `Markers` is displayed screen rotation causes `Class not found when unmarshalling` error with my custom `MyMapPoint` class - I have no idea why and what it means.
2. I click the `Marker` and then `InfoWindow`. After this I press hardware back button. Now I can see the `Map` but with no `Markers` and centered in `0,0` point.

**The code**

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ArrayList<MyMapPoint> mPoints = new ArrayList<MyMapPoint>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mPoints.add(new MyMapPoint(1, new LatLng(20, 10), 
                "test point", "description", null));            
            mPoints.add(new MyMapPoint(2, new LatLng(10, 20), 
                "test point 2", "second description", null));

            Fragment fragment = MyMapFragment.newInstance(mPoints);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.contentPane, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contentPane"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

map_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyMapFragment

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnInfoWindowClickListener {

    public static final String KEY_POINTS = "points";

    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private HashMap<MyMapPoint, Marker> mPoints = 
        new HashMap<MyMapPoint, Marker>();

    public static MyMapFragment newInstance(ArrayList<MyMapPoint> points) {
        MyMapFragment fragment = new MyMapFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_POINTS, points);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        MyMapPoint[] points = mPoints.keySet().toArray(
            new MyMapPoint[mPoints.size()]);
        outState.putParcelableArray(KEY_POINTS, points);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getArguments();
            if ((extras != null) && extras.containsKey(KEY_POINTS)) {
                for (Parcelable pointP : extras.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_POINTS)) {
                    mPoints.put((MyMapPoint) pointP, null);
                }
            }
        } else {
            MyMapPoint[] points = (MyMapPoint[]) savedInstanceState
                .getParcelableArray(KEY_POINTS);
            for (MyMapPoint point : points) {
                mPoints.put(point, null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
        mMapView = (MapView) layout.findViewById(R.id.map);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        addMapPoints();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    };

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((MapView) getView().findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        addMapPoints();
    }

    private void addMapPoints() {
        if (mMap != null) {
            HashMap<MyMapPoint, Marker> toAdd = 
                new HashMap<MyMapPoint, Marker>();
            for (Entry<MyMapPoint, Marker> entry : mPoints.entrySet()) {
                Marker marker = entry.getValue();
                if (marker == null) {
                    MyMapPoint point = entry.getKey();
                    marker = mMap.addMarker(point.getMarkerOptions());
                    toAdd.put(point, marker);
                }
            }
            mPoints.putAll(toAdd);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Fragment fragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance();
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.contentPane, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    public static class MyMapPoint implements Parcelable {
        private static final int CONTENTS_DESCR = 1;

        public int objectId;
        public LatLng latLng;
        public String title;
        public String snippet;

        public MyMapPoint(int oId, LatLng point, 
            String infoTitle, String infoSnippet, String infoImageUrl) {
            objectId = oId;
            latLng = point;
            title = infoTitle;
            snippet = infoSnippet;
        }

        public MyMapPoint(Parcel in) {
            objectId = in.readInt();
            latLng = in.readParcelable(LatLng.class.getClassLoader());
            title = in.readString();
            snippet = in.readString();
        }

        public MarkerOptions getMarkerOptions() {
            return new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                .title(title).snippet(snippet);
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return CONTENTS_DESCR;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeInt(objectId);
            dest.writeParcelable(latLng, 0);
            dest.writeString(title);
            dest.writeString(snippet);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyMapPoint> CREATOR = 
            new Parcelable.Creator<MyMapPoint>() {
            public MyMapPoint createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new MyMapPoint(in);
            }

            public MyMapPoint[] newArray(int size) {
                return new MyMapPoint[size];
            }
        };

    }
}
```

If you need to take a look at any other file - let me know. [Here](http://www.scio.pl/maptest.tgz) you can find a complete project, you just have to put your own Maps API KEY in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**EDIT**

I managed to make the example even more simple and updated the code above.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is my fix to the first problem:

It seems that `Map` is trying to unparcel all the bundle, not just it's own information when I call `mMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` and it has problem with it if I'm using my custom `Parcelable` class. The solution that worked for me was removing my extras from `savedInstanceState` as soon as I used them - before I call Map's `onCreate()`. I do it with `savedInstanceState.remove(MY_KEY)`. Another thing I had to do was to call `mMap.onSaveInstanceState()` before adding my own information to `outState` in `Fragment's` `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` function.

And here's how I handled the second one:

I simplified the example project to the bare bones. I was adding raw `Markers` to the map and if I replace the `Fragment` with map with another one then after clicking "back" I still got "nulled" map.
So I did two things:

1. saving `CameraPosition` in `onPause()` function to restore it in `onResume()`
2. setting `mMap` to null in `onPause()` so when the `Fragment` comes back, the `Markers` are added again by the `addMapPoints()` function (I had to change it a little bit since I was saving and checking `Markers` id's).

Here are code samples:

```
private CameraPosition cp;
```

...

```
public void onPause() {
    mMapView.onPause();
    super.onPause();

    cp = mMap.getCameraPosition();
    mMap = null;
}
```

...

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mMapView.onResume();
    if (cp != null) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));
        cp = null;
    }
}
```

And to update the camera position in `onResume()` I had to manually initialize maps. I did it in `setUpMap()`:

```
private void setUpMap() {
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    }
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    addMapPoints();
}
```

I realize that those aren't real solutions - just overrides but it's the best I can do for now and the project must go on. If anyone finds cleaner fixes I'll be grateful for letting me know about them.

Comment: Cheers for your answer re the Map attempting to unparcel the whole Bundle, I implemented your suggestion ages ago, but recently added a `ViewPager` to my Fragment which caused the `BadParcelableException` again. Turns out the `ViewPager`'s saved state can't be unparcelled either as it's from the Support Library so I opted to copy the map state into a new Bundle instead of removing all the parcels I knew about, my answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24651246/1007151

Answer (score 1):

Came here in search of any hints regarding `onSaveInstance` and `NullPointerException`. I have tried various workarounds including the one mentioned by @Izydorr but have had no luck. The issue was with `FragmentPagerAdapter` - the adapter of the `ViewPager` that was hosting my fragments that were embedding the `MapView`s. After having it changed to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` the NPEs have gone away. Whew!

Answer (score 0):

Implements your fragment/activity with **`GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener`** and override method `onCameraChange` and into you can save the new camera position, and `onResume` use

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPositionSaved));
```

Comment: This Interface is now deprecated.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727517/oncamerachangelistener-is-deprecated