# OnCameraChangeListener() is deprecated

Tags: android, listener, deprecated

Today, looking back at my old code, I've found out that **OnCameraChangeListener()** is now deprecated.

I'm finding difficult to understand how to fix this piece of code of mine:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        // Cleaning all the markers.
        if (mGoogleMap != null) {
            mGoogleMap.clear();
        }

        mPosition = cameraPosition.target;
        mZoom = cameraPosition.zoom;

        if (mTimerIsRunning) {
            mDragTimer.cancel();
        }

        mDragTimer.start();
        mTimerIsRunning = true;
    }
});
```

The new listener (aka **OnCameraMoveListener()**) method **onCameraMove()** doesn't have a *CameraPosition cameraPosition* input variable, so I'm pretty lost: is there a way to recycle my old code?

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener) are some references.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In [play-services-maps 9.4.0 version of the API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap), They replaced `GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener()` with three camera listeners :

- `GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener`
- `GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener`
- `GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener`

Based on your code, I think you need to use `GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener` and `GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener` like this:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMoveStarted(int i) {
                mDragTimer.start();
                mTimerIsRunning = true;
            }
        });

        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                // Cleaning all the markers.
                if (mGoogleMap != null) {
                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                }

                mPosition = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                mZoom = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;

                if (mTimerIsRunning) {
                    mDragTimer.cancel();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm calling an api on `setOnCameraIdleListener` and It plots markers in the map, but when I click on the `marker`, the `setOnCameraIdleListener` is again called, what to do?

Comment: @RohitKhatri, you should call `googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(null)` at the end of that listener.

Answer (score 32):

In the new model for [camera change events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events#camera_change_events), you are correct that the `CameraPosition` is not passed into the listener.

Instead, you should just use [getCameraPosition()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getCameraPosition()) whenever you specifically need it (i.e., when the move starts, mid-move, canceled, or finished/returned to idle).

Comment: Which would be easy enough - if getCameraPosition would not allocate memory and cause my app to stutter when simply calling getCameraPosition on every callback due to gc runs. :/

Comment: @MatthiasSchicker - feel free to [file an issue against the Maps SDK](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/)

Comment: It actually was a known issue with the Google Maps SDK (https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6483) but it seems to be fixed now. Sorry, wasn't up-to-date.

Answer (score 10):

`onnCameraChangeListener()` is deprecated now, you can use

```
mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener { reason: Int ->
            when (reason) {
                GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE -> {
                    Log.d("camera", "The user gestured on the map.")
                }
                GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener
                        .REASON_API_ANIMATION -> {
                    Log.d("camera", "The user tapped something on the map.")
                }
                GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener
                        .REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION -> {
                    Log.d("camera", "The app moved the camera.")
                }
            }
        }

mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener {
    val midLatLng: LatLng = mMap.cameraPosition.target//map's center position latitude & longitude
        }

mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener {

        }
```

Here `mMap` is `GoogleMap` object and I am calling it inside

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
        mMap = map as GoogleMap
        //your stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

It is advisable to use newly introduced four camera listeners (`OnCameraIdleListener`, `OnCameraMoveListener`, `OnCameraMoveStartedListener`,`OnCameraMoveCanceledListener`), but if you still want to go with `setOnCameraChangeListener` use specific version of `android-maps-utils`(Given below)

> compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'

in your module level gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

use **mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener** instead of **mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener**.

```
mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                 mPosition = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                 mZoom = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;

                double lat =  mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
                double lng =  mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;


           }
        });
```