# Google Maps Android Clustering OnCameraChangeListener() deprecated

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Using the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering), I successfully implemented clustering in my Android app. Since OnCameraChangeListener() is now deprecated in com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0 is there a new way to implement the part below?

```
private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
```

EDIT:

I tried directly replacing setOnCameraChangeListener by setOnCameraMoveListener like

```
googleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(mClusterManager);
```

This does not work since setOnCameraMoveListener() is expecting an object of class OnCameraMoveListener. Casting mClusterManager does not work either.

```
googleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener((GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener) mClusterManager);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried using `OnCameraMoveListener()` which, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener), is one of the given replacement for the deprecated `OnCameraChangeListener()`? Did it not work for you? Please share code snippets and error/s shown in the logs if there are any.

Comment: Edited to show what I've tried.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use

> gooleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);

instead of

> googleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(mClusterManager);

You can to search for the source code of ClusterManager and you will see that ClusterManager implements the new OnCameraIdleListener.

Also you need to update to new android-maps-utils:0.4.4

> (compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4')

Good luck and vote up... ;-)

Comment: It doesn't support MultiListener. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @KasparTr make a new class overrides clustermanager like this class MyClusterManager<T : ClusterItem>(context: Context?, map: GoogleMap?)
  : ClusterManager<T>(context, map) {

  override fun onCameraIdle() {
    super.onCameraIdle()
    Log.e("CAMERA", "CAMERA IDLE")
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to use newly introduced four camera listeners (`OnCameraIdleListener`, `OnCameraMoveListener`, `OnCameraMoveStartedListener`,`OnCameraMoveCanceledListener`), but if you still want to go with `setOnCameraChangeListener` use specific version of `android-maps-utils`(Given below)

> compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'

in your module level gradle file. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727517/oncamerachangelistener-is-deprecated/39209189#39209189) answer if you want to implement new methods.

Answer (score -1):

As per the documentation, this interface has been deprecated and replaced by more granular options which you could use.

> This interface was deprecated.
>   Replaced by GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener and GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener. The order in which the deprecated onCameraChange method will be called in relation to the methods in the new camera change listeners is undefined.

Comment: I know this but would it be applicable for the class ClusterManager<T> for clustering.