# play-services:9.4.0 and ClusterManager

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been using my `ClusterManager` with `setOnCameraChangeListener` however I have now found that with the newest play services this method is now deprecated.

What is the correct way to now have my `ClusterManager` handling camera change events?

Having a look at: [OnCameraChangeListener() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727517/oncamerachangelistener-is-deprecated)

I tried:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(mClusterManager);
```

However I end up with and error:

> setOnCameraMoveListener in GoogleMap cannot be applied to ClusterManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener()`. It is also an alternative way for the deprecated `GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener`.

So use this

```
mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
```

instead of

```
mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(mClusterManager);
```

I also found this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095415/google-maps-android-clustering-oncamerachangelistener-deprecated) that says that in order to use `OnCameraIdleListener`, you need to update to new android-maps-utils:0.4.4 (compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4').

For more information, check also this [github](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java).