# OnCameraIdleListener not found ( OnCameraChangeListener() is deprecated ) _ Android studio?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I was work on my project and work good but suddenly get me an error :

[image]

Here is my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    int minSdk = hasProperty('devMinSdk') ? devMinSdk.toInteger() : 16
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion minSdk
        applicationId "com.ir.zanis.marketing_manager"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/androiddbviewer.jar')
}
```

In my code show me :

[image]

Comment: @  IntelliJ Amiya. Not work .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727517/oncamerachangelistener-is-deprecated

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya. Please see my question I edited it .

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya. Your link for response is true . Answer the question for vote . Thanks a lot

Comment: Honestly speaking , i am here for knowledge not for more vote .My request to you please vote up above url's original user .

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya. Nice to meet you .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

quick solution

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.2
```

Comment: Please check above comments

Comment: For the quick solution it is true . But I updated all of my codes to help @IntelliJ Amiya with this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727517/oncamerachangelistener-is-deprecated