# Errors with Google Maps Android API V2 in HTC Explorer

Tags: android

I have created an App, that using Google Maps API V2. 
My app has run on Sony XS and Galaxy Tab but it cannot run on HTC Explorer (Android v 2.3.5).

Min sdk is "8" in my Manifest file.

My LogFile:

```
07-03 09:05:25.332: D/dalvikvm(2287): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
07-03 09:05:25.332: W/dalvikvm(2287): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 28
07-03 09:05:25.332: D/dalvikvm(2287): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
07-03 09:05:25.332: D/dalvikvm(2287): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
07-03 09:05:25.352: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2287): Google Play services is missing.
07-03 09:05:25.352: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2287): Google Play services is missing.
07-03 09:05:25.362: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2287): Google Play services is missing.
07-03 09:05:25.362: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2287): Google Play services is missing.
07-03 09:05:25.362: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2287): Google Play services is missing.
07-03 09:05:25.392: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2287): Google Play services is missing.
07-03 09:05:25.432: D/WindowManagerImpl(2287): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4078ae68
07-03 09:05:25.442: D/AndroidRuntime(2287): Shutting down VM
07-03 09:05:25.442: W/dalvikvm(2287): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x402445a0)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.binhanh.fasttaxi/com.binhanh.fasttaxi.FastTaxiActivivty}: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.x.b(Unknown Source)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.aW(Unknown Source)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(Unknown Source)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at com.binhanh.gmap.ManagerMap.<init>(ManagerMap.java:136)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at com.binhanh.fasttaxi.FastTaxiActivivty.onCreate(FastTaxiActivivty.java:54)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
07-03 09:05:25.442: E/AndroidRuntime(2287):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you doing the whole isGooglePlayServicesAvailable thing somewhere? If not, you need to. From the docs "It is up to you choose the appropriate place in your app to do the following steps to check for a valid Google Play services APK." http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html.

Comment: I have done setup sdk (so my app can run on other devices -Android V 4.x)

Comment: Have you tried executing MapsInitializer.initialize(Context) prior to your fromResource call ? (as described in  http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html)

Comment: I have called but GooglePlayServicesNotAvailable.
The GoogleMap built-in app can run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution at:

[Google Maps Android API v2 throws GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException, out of date, SupportMapFragment.getMap() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722192/google-maps-android-api-v2-throws-googleplayservicesnotavailableexception-out-o)

The error cause:
My phone is a new device, it have not updated the last GooglePlayService.

Thank your supports,