# Map-Fragment (v2) Nullpointer (issue under Lollipop?)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

I spotted a bug in my app when I launch it in Android Lollipop. Logcat says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
```

This error is only shown in Android Lollipop, the *exact* *same* app is running without issues at other devices*.

---

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_side_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/BlueGreyL3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/map_margin_left_24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/map_margin_left_24dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- MAP -->
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/location_map"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Ads -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlay_wrb"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Google Map v2 Fragment is loaded in my class `LocationFragments.java` by calling

```
// View 
try {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_fragment, container, false);
    sMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();
    mSideHolder = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.map_side_holder);
```

I use AndroidStudio so here is `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
   }

[...]

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
}
```

and the Manifest:

```
    <!-- Google Play -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <!-- Maps -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value=""/>
```

**I don't get any idea, what I've done wrong.. Is it possible that the issue is caused by Lollipop itself?**

Thanks in advance,

Martin

---

*Test Devices:

1. HTC One M8 - 4.4.4 (GPE / API 19) -> works
2. Samsung S4 Mini - 4.4.2 (CM11 / API 19) -> works
3. Samsung S2 - 4.0.3 (ICS / API 15) -> works
4. HTC One M8 - 5.0 (LL / API 20) -> error while loading map
5. Nexus 5 - 5.0 (LL / API 20) -> error while loading map

Comment: Try to move the `getMap` code to the `onResume`

Comment: Works! Thank you so much, saved my weekend ;)
But why is that? Is instantiation of the Maps Fragment by ART not as fast as it goes by good old Dalvik?
If you want I will accept your answer.

Comment: Glad to help :) I tried my best to explain what i dont really know in my answer LOL

Comment: Edit: sadly it doesn't work. I just oversaw a try catch... Still the same error on getMap()...
I will read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722192/google-maps-android-api-v2-throws-googleplayservicesnotavailableexception-out-o

Comment: Yes, try to update your `google play services`. I use the latest one with `onResume` and the error never happened again

Comment: Do you use the SupportFragmentManager or the "normal" FragmentManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the `getMap` to the `onResume`. To be honest, i dont know the exact answer, its just trial and error and voila! its working.

But what i think is moving it to `onResume` will make sure the `Activity/Fragment` has been created (`onCreate`) and started (`onStart`).

UPDATE

And update your `google play services` to the latest version.

Comment: Should'nt you put that code into `onViewCreated()` if it's a `Fragment`?

Comment: @shkschneider Thanks for reminding. I updated my answer. I think the code is safer in `onResume`, both `fragment` and `activity` has it on its lifecycle

Answer (score 6):

I've got the exact same problem under HTC M8 5.0 but only moving the code to `onResume` did not do the trick. Instead I found that it worked if I used `getChildFragment()` instead of the normal `getFragmentManager()`.

The code I now use to get the reference to the map object (under `onResume`):

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapsfragment_map);

if(mapFragment == null){
    return;
}

map = mapFragment.getMap();
```

I hope this maybe helps!

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem. Problem with FragmentManager. 
The best solution for me is:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        sMap = ((MapFragment) (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();
    } else {
        sMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();
    }
```