# Fatal Lint Error during exporting of signed app

Tags: android, fatal-error, android-lint

I'm trying to export a signed android app, but I encountered this lint error:

[image]

And when I go into the xml to look at it, this happens:

[image]

Is there a way to solve this so that I can continue to sign the app? I don't need them translated since it'll all be in English anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was with Android Lint. For solving this go to `Preferences -> Android -> Lint error Checking.`

There you can see a list of error checking methods.

- Scroll to **Correctness:Messages**.
- Change the severity of **Missing Translation** to be something other
  than error, say warning

Comment: Thanks this seem to help address the problem!

Answer (score 8):

Window--> Preferences --> Android -->Lint Error Checking --> Uncheck the second check box that says -Run full error check.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't. I've already tried this step as shown. I am still not allowed to export as it will say "Project name contains unsupported characters!" in the export window that is launched.

Comment: That's a different issue. Btw what is the project name?

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't want to translate on all languages and errors similar to that try the following step

**Project** -> **Properties**, find ***Android Lint Preferences***, in top to right click ***Configure Workspace Settings***... -> Uncheck ***Run full error check when exporting app***.