# Android Google Maps API v2: Authorization failure at different laptops

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I've followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure) and [here](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) to create a `MapView` in our teams project which we sync with svn. After following the steps, `MapView` was running smooth, but only on my laptop. My project members are always getting

```
02-06 13:27:37.327: E/Google Maps Android API(19490): Authorization failure.
```

when opening the `MapView`. So I deleted the old one and generated a new SHA1 fingerprint for a new Google API Key on another laptop with my Google Account with:

`keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -v`

So now it's working on the other laptop where I generated the SHA1 fingerprint but when I try to run the project on my laptop I'm now getting the

```
02-06 13:29:51.280: E/Google Maps Android API(20262): Authorization failure.
```

Error.

We are not using `proguard-project.txt`, we tried different devices where `google-play-services` is installed and included `/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib` as a library. We also tried to generate multiple API Keys but only one was working.

What are we doing wrong? Do we have to use different Google Accounts to create individual keys?

Comment: Thanks for asking this. It helped to find a solution for my own problem! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here.

1. Add a separate line to the api key for each device you have.
2. Extract the api key to a file (eg. `map_key.xml`) and reference this file from the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

   ```
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key_v2" />
   ```

   Add this file to your .gitignore - so now each project member can override with its own key.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the Google API Console:

> API requests are sent directly to Google from your clients' Android
>   devices. Google verifies that each request originates from an Android
>   application that matches one of the certificate SHA1 fingerprints and
>   package names listed below. You can discover the SHA1 fingerprint of
>   your developer certificate using the following command[...]
>
> **One SHA1 certificate fingerprint and package name (separated by a semicolon)
>   per line.**

Highlight here on **one per line**.

[image: Screenshot of Google Maps API Key - Configure Android Key]`

For each laptop where you build your app you have to generate an SHA1 fingerprint and add it in the API Console.