# Android Maps APIv2 -- distributing an adhoc build

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, android-keystore

I need a bit of guidance here.

I've got a "rescue" project going on and have had to replace google maps api v1 for api v2.  None of that has been a major problem (thanks to stackoverflow) but one thing I can't seem to get my head around is providing a release with working maps.

- My code is functioning via the Eclipse build to device.  I'm happily testing away.
- I've got a signed debug key following the steps at google dev

When I send a release to the client (via HockeyApp) they can't see the maps.   I get that it requires a release key and followed the steps here to set up the "public" API.

I did the following steps per the directions:

```
keytool -list -keystore mynamedkey
keytool -list -v -keystore mynamedkey -alias mynamedkey
```

I then copied and pasted to get my API key.  Pasted it in the AndroidManifest.  Sent a build out. Maps are still not visible.

Is there another setting I have to do?

edit:  I'm signing the application with the same key I used to get the maps release API.

Comment: Reviewing ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219501/google-maps-not-showing-on-android-in-release-mode?rq=1

Comment: Reviewing ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the whole process again and it works.  I'm going to go with user error + confusing process.  There's lots of articles here that list that process.  This question can be deleted or locked.