# Errors running sample code for Google Map API v2

Tags: android

I am trying to run the sample code of Google map API v2. I am getting the following errors.

```
04-23 08:54:23.178: E/Trace(1703): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-23 08:54:24.489: W/dalvikvm(1703): VFY: unable to resolve static field 859 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
04-23 08:54:24.489: D/dalvikvm(1703): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
04-23 08:54:24.508: D/AndroidRuntime(1703): Shutting down VM
04-23 08:54:24.508: W/dalvikvm(1703): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.swetha.googlemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-23 08:54:24.538: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 08:59:24.708: I/Process(1703): Sending signal. PID: 1703 SIG: 9
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity { GoogleMap map; @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); map=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 

map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: have you linked google play library correctly?

Comment: Have you imported google play services ? check the accepted [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure?rq=1)

Comment: From your error log it indicates that you have not included the Google Play Service library into your application. So just add that library in your application after exporting from the android sdk.

Comment: Post your code of `MainActivity.java` file.

Comment: i have imported googleplay service

Answer (score 3):

Import Google Play Services. Check [Android Maps V2 Quick Start](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) to know how to import it.

And change the line

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
```

to

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();`
```

Comment: Have you added all the required permissions like `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and meta data like `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your api key" />`

Comment: Which sample you are trying to run ? is there any link to that whole project ?

Comment: just i have followed the steps in developers.android.com

Comment: Did you change the line which I specified in my answer

Comment: i have changed the line when i am run the app again i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending from FragmentActivity means you are developing the app for target below 11.
You should use the SupportMapFragment.

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

See my blog posts i have tried to summarize all there is needed to build an App with Google Maps API V2 for Android.

1. [Solution to Problems with Maps API V2(using google_play_services_lib).](http://mzubair.com/solving-the-problemserrors-of-google-maps-api-v2/)
2. [Creating an Android App with Maps API V2 for minSDK=8 (Android 2.2 Froyo).](http://mzubair.com/creating-an-android-app-with-maps-api-v2/)
3. [Creating an Android App with Maps API V2 for minSDK=11 (Android 3.0 HoneyComb).](http://mzubair.com/creating-an-android-app-with-maps-api-v2-for-minsdk11-android-23-0-honeycomb/)