# Using the new Google Play Services

Tags: android, io, google-play-services

**I'm getting the follow error:**
google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!

Complete Console:

> [2013-05-17 16:41:50 - MapAlert] Android Launch!
>   [2013-05-17 16:41:50 - MapAlert] adb is running normally.
>   [2013-05-17 16:41:50 - MapAlert] Performing com.map.alert.StartUp activity launch
>   [2013-05-17 16:41:50 - MapAlert] Automatic Target Mode: using device '0288500541404557'
>   [2013-05-17 16:41:55 - MapAlert] Uploading MapAlert.apk onto device '0288500541404557'
>   [2013-05-17 16:41:57 - MapAlert] Installing MapAlert.apk...
>   [2013-05-17 16:42:55 - MapAlert] Success!
>   [2013-05-17 16:42:56 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!
>   [2013-05-17 16:42:56 - MapAlert] Starting activity com.map.alert.StartUp on device 0288500541404557

I have seen the new thing on google I/o and a saw you could use the new Google Play Services. I've added the library follow this guide: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

I also did found something on the net that the app on my phone should be updated but i'm already running 3.1.36. This is the new version where it should work with.

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse? IntelliJ? Android Studio?

Comment: @loeschg I'm using Eclipse, just updated the SDK to V22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using IntelliJ or Android Studio, the following StackOverflow link might be your ticket. The selected answer is pretty thorough. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598478/413254

Comment: Thanks, I see an example directory in there, maybe I can do something with that.

Comment: Thanks, it did help! I've got it working by **Project propeties** > **android** and added the library there.

Comment: I had this problem even after adding the library as above but I think I originally incorrectly added a ref to it also in into the projects in Java build path. After removing the library from the projects in Java build path and re adding as above comment, the problem went away. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

yuor answer has two steps :

1.remove the google_play_services-lib reference from the Java build path

2.add the library reference in Properties | Android | Library references

Answer (score -2):

The solution was in a comment to the answer for this question:

[Using the new Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612327/using-the-new-google-play-services)

Steps:

remove the google_play_services-lib reference from the Java build path
add the library reference in Properties | Android | Library references

Comment: Buddy, The question you linked is actually this question you are looking at. You should not copy answers like that.