# Android - Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk! error

Tags: android, service, shared-libraries, runtime-error

I am trying to use the new Google Play Services for Google Plus integration from this link: http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.sg/2013/05/google-plus-integration-in-android.html

I was able to get everything right except when i try to run it, it provide me with this error

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing com.anky.googleplus.MainActivity activity launch
Automatic Target Mode: using device 'CB5A1MQW4P'
Uploading GooglePlusDemo.apk onto device 'CB5A1MQW4P'
Installing GooglePlusDemo.apk...
Success!
Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!
Starting activity com.anky.googleplus.MainActivity on device CB5A1MQW4P
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.anky.googleplus/.MainActivity }
```

I did reference the library via eclipse Properties > Android > Add Library like what is done here: [Using the new Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612327/using-the-new-google-play-services)
This error still occured. Any suggest and feed back is welcome.

Answer (score 50):

When Adding refenced libraries we need only google-play-services_lib.jar.So that we need to remove the project from your project.

Project->Properties->javaBuildPath->Project->select google-play-services->remove.

clean and build.

Comment: Why in the world would the other way not work if Google's own instructions say to do it that way? Ugh. Anyways, thanks a lot. This fixed for me.

Comment: Ugh, I'd had it referencing just the jar.  Then I was having another problem, so I figured I'd double-check my Play Services references.  I came across [the instructions from Google](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) that `unexpected62` is probably talking about.  That seemed to be the right way, so I ended up following Google's own directions and breaking everything.  Thanks for re-clarifying!

Comment: OMFG.. thanks so much for this... I was starting to lose hair with this problem....

Comment: Holy Moly, it worked for me too! And as @Shradha says, I have no freaking idea why it did

Answer (score 6):

Well i had this same problem.. I then found out that  i had incorrectly referenced it first in the java build path before referencing it from the Properties > Android > Add Library .
**Solution** 
First remove both  the reference from the java build   and the  Properties > Android > Add Library then  reference google_Play_services_lib from Properties > Android > Add Library again.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't install the google-play-services_lib APK, you should reference it on your project as an Android Library Project and the JAR will be included inside your APK.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

This link teaches you how to reference an android library project:

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: May I know what JAR file that you are referring to? Is it the android-support-v13.jar? I followed the other steps and the problem still persist

Comment: The JAR file will be generated and referenced automatically if you properly set the google-play-services_lib library as an Android Library Project. Are you using Eclipse to build and run your code?

Comment: Apparently I did not create the oAuth for my application. I solved the problem by following this link: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_3_initialize_the_plusclient

Answer (score 5):

In your manifiest file put it inside

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was fixed by checking Android Private Dependencies checkbox in google-play-services_lib eclipse project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export tab. It was checked as well in the main project which has the reference to google-play-services_lib. 
I still get the `Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!` error in console but the maps activities run OK, while before the change I got run time errors and the application crashed.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to copy google-play-services.jar to libs folder of the project. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think the device on which you are trying to run the Google Play Services does not contain the Google Play services APK.

Check this link on Android Developers for more clearance

[Ensuring Devices Have the Google Play services APK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: Im quite sure mine have the services apk as i am able to find it in my app manager in settings

Answer (score -1):

Check whether that the library project is added into project, if not then check whether the library project and your project is in same directory.