# Android (Eclipse) cannot find google-play-services_lib.apk tried multiple solutions

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am creating an android application that displays a map based on the Google maps API, which should be compatible with android 2.3 API level 10.

I have tried all the solutions i could come across such as:

1. imported existing code into my project (checked copy to workspace and its the directory google-play-services-lib)
2. added the correct meta and such in my XML (see below)
3. I have tried setting up the emulator with several different settings

The android application runs fine, but when this page is shown is exits.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <permission
        android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <!-- Accessing camera hardware -->
    <!-- putting android.hardware.camera prevents non-camera devices using this app -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.StartScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.CreateWalkActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_walk" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.HelpScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help_screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.WalkRecording"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_walk_recording" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBKYpKfU4zn-3IBkskKsLbwRsQ1-IqFldk"
        />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</manifest>
```

The xml displaying the map:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".WalkRecording" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the java code for the map class

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class WalkRecording extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_walk_recording);

        map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.walk_recording, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The eclipse trace:

```
[2013-11-22 23:03:07 - WalkingTours] ------------------------------
[2013-11-22 23:03:07 - WalkingTours] Android Launch!
[2013-11-22 23:03:07 - WalkingTours] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-22 23:03:07 - WalkingTours] Performing dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.StartScreen activity launch
[2013-11-22 23:03:07 - WalkingTours] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'mapTestAPI16'
[2013-11-22 23:03:07 - WalkingTours] Uploading WalkingTours.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-11-22 23:03:07 - WalkingTours] Installing WalkingTours.apk...
[2013-11-22 23:03:12 - WalkingTours] Success!
[2013-11-22 23:03:12 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!
[2013-11-22 23:03:12 - WalkingTours] Starting activity dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.StartScreen on device emulator-5554
[2013-11-22 23:03:14 - WalkingTours] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02/.StartScreen }
```

Comment: By the way, API level 22 doesn't exist. Android 4.4 is 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your error log, there is one solution provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17397908/959260). Dont import google-play-services_lib APK, you should reference it on your project as an Android Library Project.

Comment: i have done that, when i go project>properties>Android it shows as added, but i still get this error

Comment: i think just adding the jar seems to have worked but i have a clas sno def found error on the class which holds the map that i  have to sort out first

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Look at project: Properties-> Java Build Path under projects remove google-play-services_lib. 
Not necessary to include in build also as a project.