# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging after ADT update

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, google-cloud-messaging

I'm getting this error:

> 07-16 13:56:12.341: E/AndroidRuntime(23287):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging

after I updated ADT last week. The code:

```
public GCMRegisterTask(Context acontext) {
    this.context = acontext;
    if (gcm == null) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
    }
}
```

The project doesn't show any compilation error, but when I try to debug this in my phone(Android 4.2, I've also tried in one table with Android 4.4) this error occurs. I've tried all the workarounds:

**The Android Private Libraries export is checked:**

[image: The library is perfectly setted]

[image]

[image: The export checkbox is ok]

**I've also tried including only the google-play-services.jar in the libs/ folder and I'm getting the same error.**

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the problem:

[Android - Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk! error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756561/android-could-not-find-google-play-services-lib-apk-error)

I removed google-play-services from java build path->Projects and it worked!