# GCM example project error message "Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk"

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

With the example code provided on http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/#git%2Fgcm-client, the application launch protocol contains a message about a missing APK.

```
[2013-06-22 10:28:24 - GCMClientNewAPI] ------------------------------
[2013-06-22 10:28:24 - GCMClientNewAPI] Android Launch!
[2013-06-22 10:28:24 - GCMClientNewAPI] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-22 10:28:24 - GCMClientNewAPI] Performing com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity activity launch
[2013-06-22 10:28:29 - GCMClientNewAPI] Uploading GCMClientNewAPI.apk onto device '015d3e63881c020d'
[2013-06-22 10:28:30 - GCMClientNewAPI] Installing GCMClientNewAPI.apk...
[2013-06-22 10:29:07 - GCMClientNewAPI] Success!
[2013-06-22 10:29:07 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!
[2013-06-22 10:29:07 - GCMClientNewAPI] Starting activity com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity on device 015d3e63881c020d
[2013-06-22 10:29:07 - GCMClientNewAPI] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.google.android.gcm.demo.app/.DemoActivity }
```

However the application is able to connect to Play services, and get a registration id. Also sending messages seems to work fine - at least no errors are logged.

The library project is referenced by the demo project in the Android settings (as also can be seen in the project.properties file).

I am testing on a Nexus 7 device with the current Android 4.2.2 version, and the current Google Play Services version 3.1.36 (669520-30).

What could cause this Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk message?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution was in a comment to the answer for this question:

[Using the new Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612327/using-the-new-google-play-services)

Steps:

1. remove the google_play_services-lib reference from the Java build path
2. add the library reference in Properties | Android | Library references

Comment: THanks buddy... You are champ~~~

Comment: Thanks ! It works - although the error for me had no side effects - i had already added the library reference.

Comment: This compiles, but when I go to run the project I get an 'Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded. GC overhead limit exceeded.'

Comment: Ok, please see this link to fix the  'GC overhead limit exceeded.' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080078/eclipse-crashes-with-a-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error