# Android Studio : Project successfully compiled but can't access Google Play Services on device

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services

I've been trying to compile my project using Google Play Services such as Maps and GCM.

After following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243377/2644128), my project now compiles successfully and includes all the libs I need. Android Studio also has added auto-completion for GCM and Maps functions. Build target is set to `Google APIs 18`

But then, when I intent to start my app, it crashes when it hits

```
if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
                setContentView(R.layout.error_no_play);
                return;
```

or when it hits the map fragment

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gmap"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

The errors thrown are :

- When checking if GooglePlayServices is available : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil`
- For the fragment :

  .......

  ```
    08-22 20:17:56.565  20356-20356/<MY_APP> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{<MY_APP>/<MY_APP>.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
      at <MY_APP>.SearchFragment.newTab(SearchFragment.java:71)
      at <MY_APP>.SearchFragment.setupTabs(SearchFragment.java:54)
      at <MY_APP>.SearchFragment.onCreateView(SearchFragment.java:28)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5068)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
      ... 11 more
      Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
      ... 26 more
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: /data/app/<MY_APP>-2.apk
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
      ... 29 more
  ```

The Manifest file is as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="<MyApp>"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- Permissions required for GMap and Facebook to work -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="<MyApp>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="<MyApp>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- Require OpenGL ES2 for GMap -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                  android:required="true" />


    <!-- Because this app is using the GCM library to send messages, the min SDK cannot be lower
    than 8. Using SDK11-->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyPushReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gcm.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="<MyApp>" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="<MyApp>.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Facebook specific activities -->
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />

        <!-- GMap API key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="<MY_KEY>" />
        <!-- Facebook App ID -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've been dealing with this issue for 1 month now, and i still have no way to deal with it. Is it a known issue of AndroidStudio? Am i forgetting something? From what i'm reading from the error logs, it looks like the libs are not compiled with the project.

Comment: plz paste your manifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

First i doubled checked that `JAVA_HOME` system env variable was set.

When set, i got compile errors stating that one library was already added : Support v4.

Then i remembered that i was also using Facebook SDK for android studio, and that their `build.gradle` is as following and outdated :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION :** Now my facebook's `build.gradle` is as following :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

I simply replaced gradle plugin's version with the most recent one, and set the new support-v4 dependencies with the updated ones.

tl;dr: If you're using facebook SDK for Android Studio, double check that FacebookSDK's `build.gradle` is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

May be your problem is

**Fragments are not supported below 3.0 versions.But you are used**

```
Use your minimumSDk version 3.0 are above 3.0

or

Use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment
```

If you want Tutorial see this http://venkoolit.blogspot.in/2013/05/tutorial-for-develop-google-maps-in-api.html

Comment: I've updated the question and added the manifest file. Also the project compiles without any problem, it just looks like the activity can't access the Google Play classes.