# How do I migrate my Android Eclipse project to using Gradle and Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

**Background:**

I'd like to export an Android project from Eclipse into Android Studio using Gradle.

**Problem:**
After importing the Gradle project generated by the Gradle Eclipse plugin the app wouldn't run. The error message we're getting states that a module is missing, see printscreen. I am successful in generation a gradle.build-file for each of the projects/libraries and a settings.gradle for the root-project.

How do I go about doing this migration? What are some common pitfalls?

**Preconditions:**

- Android Studio 0.2.3
- JRE 1.6.0_45
- Gradle 1.7
- Mac OS X 10.8.3
- Eclipse Kepler, Build id: 20130614-0229
- [This Eclipse Gradle plugin](https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/master/README.md).

[image: Project files]
[image: Eclipse project setup]

Answer (score 0):

You should create a folder in you project's root and name it libs.
Then copy your jar file to that folder and add

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

to your build.gradle file.

If above won't work. You may need to try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services)