# Google Play Service , Using Updated Google Map V2

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services, build.gradle

i am using google play services in my project, i am trying to use google map v2 service in my app.

For this i included play services as dependency in build.gradle file as mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243377).

for now the latest version of play services is 3.2.65 and i am pointing to it. Ok.
So my question is ,In the future when google releases newer version of play services and the device has play services version above 3.2.65 which was specified in build.gradle file, will cause any problem or not? And will my application adapts the latest feature of play services automatically or i have to release updates of my application every time google releases newer version of play services.

And if not then is there any other way or including play services in module dependency so that my application will always use updated version of play services.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you have to recompile your project with a newer version of the library.

Various library versions are downloaded on your machine and used to compile the project.

SDK_DIRECTORY/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms

Of course Google releases things in order to preserve compatibility, so if you don't need any new feature/API you don't have to update your project.

In your build.gradle file, you can also write in this way:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
```

So you will pick up any new 3.1.x version whatever is the latest number.

Comment: thanks fasteque ,i used the above code and no warning in stack trace is shown.

Answer (score 2):

> In the future when google releases newer version of play services and the device has play services version above 3.2.65 which was specified in build.gradle file, will cause any problem or not?

No, it won't cause any problems. Google Maps Android API v2 is developed in a forward-compatible way. No change will ever be made that can break older apps.

> And will my application adapts the latest feature of play services automatically or i have to release updates of my application every time google releases newer version of play services.

Depends. Most of the bug fixes are made in the Google Play Services app and you don't need to update client library. Because client library has almost no code, there is low chance any bug will appear there.
If you want to use new features, you will obviously have to update the library to be able to call new APIs.