# Gradle unable to resolve Play services dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've got a clean Android project with Google Play services rev. 13 installed through the SDK manager, following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services).

My `build.gradle` file is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
}
```

However, when I attempt to build this app, I get

```
Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':Maple'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Maple:_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30.
        Required by:
            MapleProject:Maple:unspecified
```

Comment: from cmd type "gradle clean cleaneclipse eclipse"

Comment: you need to have the google repository installed from the extras section of the SDK manager to get the play services working with gradle.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Install the Google Repository in the SDK manager.

Comment: +1 And why isn't this in the GCM guide/documentation? Wasted 3 hours of my life.

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out over this, the documentation doesn't mention this step AT ALL. Thanks!

Comment: Changing version worked for me. See my answer in the same thread.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you have installed Google Repository in SDK Manager, you might still see the same error.

Another possible solution is to downgrade your version.

For example, instead of

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
```

Do

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
```

Notice 11.2.0 is advertised in Google's [Set up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) page but it does not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Are you testing on Avd (Emulator or device  ?)
If emulator please check below:
I resolved this issue by creating a new avd with target version as : Google APIs(GoogleInc) API Level 18. (platform 4.3 google api required)