# MapActivity could not be found. Android Studio 0.5.1

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I am setting up google map v2 in Android. I am using the new technique on adding dependency using this link."[Android Studio with Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services)"

It did nice after synchronization, clean project and rebuild project. However I could not find the MapActivity. What seems to be the problem?

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MapActivity` was part of the Google Maps Android **v1** API which is now deprecated.

Using the Google Play Services library you will use the Google Maps Android API **v2** and then `MapActivity` is not available anymore. You need to use the `MapFragment`.

You can see an introduction on how to use the `MapFragment` in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

Comment: Yeah, I had check the classes in the Jar files and I could not found MapActivity... Man, the book that I am looking is already redundant.