# the method oncreate(bundle) of type mainActivity must override or implements a supertype method

Tags: android

i am trying to display the googlemap in my project, i'm new in android and i have this error which appears:

the method oncreate(bundle) of type mainActivity must override or implements a supertype method. i don't really know what is the problem with my code. here is my code:

can somebody please help me??thank in advance

```
package com.example.map;

import android.app.Fragment;   
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i've tried to put it public, but it doesn't change anything. this is an autogenerate code.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/22347529/3410697

Comment: i've check your link and try to follow all the step that are mention, but when i run the project into a device, they that "unfortunately map has stopped" .

Comment: mao is the name of my application @Andres M.

Comment: You should update your answer then and show us your logcat and the fragment implementation

Comment: @Andres M. gave me this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2; i've try to follow the step that are set, but when i'm running map(name of my application) i have this message:"unfortunately map has stop". so when you talk about logcat and fragment implementation you means??sorry i'm new in android

Comment: LogCat view is the view in Eclipse that shows your application logs. When it crashes, red text appears in the LogCat and allows you to track the issue and helps you solving it. Please research a little for it.

Comment: i also have this message error in my manifest.xml: "Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this   version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details." i don't no maybe it is an problem

Comment: yes, i saw it. there is red text, how can i show you it??

Comment: You have to search for a line number on your Activity. That line is what is causing your crash. Point us what is the line and maybe we can help. As for the manifest file warning, you should change your android:targetSdkVersion attribute value to 20. The warning will go away

Comment: Use MapFragment instead. Update Google Play Services library. See http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html

Comment: can somebody please tell me how can i show you my logcat?? there a lot of red text, so want to know how to fix that errors please..

Comment: here it is a part of lines of my logcat, maybe it can help me to find the line that causing that crash:

Comment: 10-13 23:59:38.420: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-13 23:59:38.420: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-13 23:59:38.420: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

Comment: i'm trying to find the line that causes my crash,somebody have an idea using the part of logcat message that i've post??

Comment: can somebody help me to get solve this issue?? i saw in my logcat an error  "java.lang.classnotfoundexception com.google.android.gms.maps.mapfragment"