# How to add library google play service in android studio successfully

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, google-play-services

I try to add library `google play service` to project via `Maven` in android studio, but it get many issues.

**First Issue** is `Multiple dex files define` :

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

I researched, changed to like this:

```
    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
}

    dependencies {

        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
       // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'{
         exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'

    }
```

But I get other error `Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23()'!`

I don't why I got this bug.

People can tell me how to add library `google play service` to project via `Maven` successfully?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I must modify my build.gradle file to look like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

Restart android studio and synchronize my project. Problem solved

Thanks all everybody

I understand about add library `google play service` in android studio when I following link: 
[Android Studio with Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services)

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on you App, then Open Module Settings

1. Right Click on your App
2. Click Open Module Settings
3. Select the Dependencies tap
4. Select the green plus(+) button to add dependencies
5. Select Library Dependency
6. Play Services
7. Sync Gradle

Answer (score -1):

Here is what the top of my build.gradle file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // http://gradleplease.appspot.com/
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}
```

As mentioned in the comment in `dependencies`, you can get the latest version of a lot of these by going to http://gradleplease.appspot.com/