# android studio "searched in the following locations"

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

Just moved to AS from Eclipse. Trying to build an existing (working) project. It keeps giving me this error

> Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/utils/AndroidStudio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.2.0/play-services-9.2.0.pom
>       file:/C:/utils/AndroidStudio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.2.0/play-services-9.2.0.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.2.0/play-services-9.2.0.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.2.0/play-services-9.2.0.jar
>   Required by:
>       :Personal_weather:unspecified

The library is not in the studio directory (AndroidStudio), it is in the SDK directory (AndroidSDK), which the installation procedure insisted upon. I have installed the google repository using SDK Manager. In project setup I have the correct location of the SDK. How do I force AS to look in the correct directory?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help files I had read so far said that I had to add classpath and compile members to the dependencies of the gradle files.
In the build.gradle for the project in dependencies I had

```
classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

But I had also added the library to the project structure via the

```
File->Project Structure->Modules->app->Dependencies
```

menu. So, on a whim, I commented out the classpath statement.

In the build.gradle for the module in dependencies I had

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

which I left in. This is now compiling. There is a lot of conflicting information around regarding AndroidStudio so trial and error seems the way to go.