# Google Play Services library is missing

Tags: android

I want to use Google Play Services as a library to my project but I can't find it in

```
extras/google/google_play_services
```

folder.

In M2 repository I found `.aar` files and my Google Play Services version is 38.

Comment: Use SDK Manager to download Google Play Service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17243377/3104050