# Compilation error in Android Studio When making a simple Google Android Maps API v2 project

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-studio, google-play-services

Recently I migrated to the New **Android Studio IDE** based on IntelliJ

The Guides i followed were:

1. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start (*for
   basics*)
2. [How can I create an Android application in Android Studio that uses the Google Maps Api v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596715/how-can-i-create-an-android-application-in-android-studio-that-uses-the-google-m)
   (*for importing the required Google Play services and support
   libraries into android studio*)

All the libraries were properly detected by Android Studio and i didn't get any 'library not found errors'. The project was shown error free. Then when i tried to compile it i got this error.

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':AID-AmritaInfoDesk:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
```

This was my **explorer.java** file

```
package com.aid.explorer;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class explorer extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.explorer);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

And this was my **explorer.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

I would like to know what went wrong. any help would be *greatly* appreciated

Comment: Then finally i got fed up of this and **switched back to Eclipse IDE** (Juno).. The Error just vanished and the maps now works properly... But i'm not closing this Question yet as i need to know what is causing such an error in Gradle-Android Studio...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was following the same instructions except I was creating a new project. Under the project structure I removed the Android-Gradle facet and was able to build successfully.  Optionally one can update the gradle build files and add the Android-Gradle facet to the play services library.

NOTE: I changed the name of Google Play Services directory.

`build.gradle` for Google Play Services library.

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('google-play-services.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aild.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` for test app.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile project(':lib-google-play-services')
    compile files('../lib-google-play-services/libs/google-play-services.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, although I had to add this to `settings.gradle`: `include ':google-play-services_lib'`

Comment: And for those who want to get ```google-play-services_lib``` imported as a Gradle project into Android Studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977739/how-to-add-gradle-backing-to-existing-project

Answer (score 0):

First you must give more information about the error.
Instead of using the external compiler you must try to use the internal compiler (changing the compiler settings)

Comment: Ok but with the external compiler option turned off you get more information about errors