# plugin with id not found and Module is not backed by gradle Error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error initially before running the project in Message Gradle Sync.

> Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

After running the project I am getting the below error:

> Module `ListViewMaster` is not backed by Gradle.

Below I am posted the codes related to that:

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mindmine.com.welcometol"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
}
```

My **Gradle** version is 2.2.1

My **Android Studio** Version 1.0.1

Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977739/how-to-add-gradle-backing-to-existing-project

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't bring the jar with the plugin to the classpath of the build script. You need to add the following piece to your `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
```