# How to add gradle to Android Studio project?

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to find the build.gradle file in my project. The group project is in a github repo and other group members have worked on it in Eclipse.

I have tried various ways of importing the project into Android Studio and I can't figure out how to add Gradle to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You would need to migrate the project to android studio.http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: Take a look at this http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: Also relevant. The Android Development team [stopped supporting Eclipse](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Gradle backing to existing project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977739/how-to-add-gradle-backing-to-existing-project)

Comment: Personally I could never get any solution to work correctly so I created a new project and copied in my existing code, resources, assets, etc.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a new project with the new structure and moving over your classes, you can simply drag and drop between two android studio instances. It will give you less pain in the long run than maintaining a weird middleground. One of our old applications used migration and has the old folder structure, while it works its a bit of an extra headache when working with it.

Comment: Would it be simpler to open this project in eclipse?