# Not able to use Google Play Services library in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

Moving to Android Studio, I'm no more able to add and use the Google Play Servies Library.

I create a simple project, I add the library as module, the sign-in button in my layout but when I run the app crashes because of ClassNotFoundException...

Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: Ended up adding the .jar as a Library so I'm now able to use it.

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596715/how-can-i-create-an-android-application-in-android-studio-that-uses-the-google-m

Comment: If you come here looking for a solution, please do not add the Google Play Services Library as a .jar as I've suggested here above.

In Android Studio is now possible to use the official Maven repository as explained here: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/4Yhpn6p9icf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two years I created this question a lot of things has changed concerning `Android Studio` and what you have to do to use the `Google Play Services library`.
I think I can answer myself reporting the important steps of the official documentation which can be found here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

I also assume you already have installed an updated version of `Android Studio` with the latest `SDK Tools`.

So here is the procedure:

**1** - Add the required SDK packages from the SDK Manager:

- Google Repository
- Google Play services

Official documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

**2** - Open the `build.gradle` file inside your **application module** directory and add a new build rule under `dependencies` for the latest version of play-services.
For example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Be sure you update this version number each time Google Play services is updated.

**3** - Save the changes and click **Sync Project with Gradle Files** in the toolbar.

From version 6.5, you can selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app.
In the official documentation you can find the complete list of the `individual APIs` and corresponding `build.gradle` descriptions.

Package summary: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/package-summary

When you create a new project, Android Studio also provides a Google Play Services Activity template.