# Android Studio Maps Api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

My code works perfectly on eclipse. I have created a new project on Android Studio and added my classes, I have also followed this popular tutorial answer [How can I create an Android application in Android Studio that uses the Google Maps Api v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596715/how-can-i-create-an-android-application-in-android-studio-that-uses-the-google-m/16598726#16598726)

Now the code doesn't show any red flags and it detects the imports fine but when I build the project I get these errors:
Gradle: package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist
Gradle: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist

On a side note I have attempted to import the MAPS sample project like the tutorial says and that has worked fine but I do not know why my new project gives me these errors even though I have followed the tutorial to the letter.

Any idea guys?

Comment: @RachelGallen Google Maps Android API v2 is not deprecated. Google Maps Javascript API v2 is.

Comment: @MaciejGórski my bad i'll delete the commment!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you created a new project (which uses Gradle) and then followed the tutorial, it's completely wrong.

When using Gradle (which new projects do by default), you cannot use the UI to add dependencies. You need to add them manually in build.gradle.

It's a crappy solution right now and we're working to make this better.

Comment: Thought this should be shared in the accepted answer as its the only solution I have found so far. Step by Step Guide: http://aetherstudios.net/pages/gradle.html

Comment: And example of the modification to the build.gradle file would be awesome.  Looks like you could copy it from the following answer.

Answer (score 6):

In short words:

1. Run Android Studio
2. Create new project
3. Create new module of Android Library type, remember to set the package name to `com.google.android.gms`
4. Copy `res`, `src` folders and `AndroidManifest.xml` file from `google-play-services_lib` (you can find it in your SDK folder if you installed it using SDK Manager) to the appropriate folder in your library module (`[Project]/[Library]/src/main`)
5. Remove `android-support-v4.jar` from `libs` folder under your library module, live only `google-play-services.jar` and `google-play-services.jar.properties` files there.
6. Make sure your `build.gradle` file in library module contains following:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
   }
   ```
7. Make sure your build.gradle for application module contains following:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
       compile project(':[LibraryModuleName]')
   }
   ```
8. Make sure your settings.gradle contain following:

   ```
   include ':MapStudio', ':[LibraryModuleName]'
   ```
9. You can grab layout and manifest settings from Google Maps API v2 tutorial
10. Keep in mind that `android-support-v4.jar` is neccessary only when you want to support Android v2

You can find more detailed description on [my blog](http://android.rzeszow.net/?p=79).

Comment: We don't allow this.  However, you can [edit] to provide enough details to answer the question, while still pointing to your related blog post.  If you want to do that, then flag afterwards to have this undeleted.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried and failed many a tutorial on this, but finally find a simple solution that seem to work.

I just installed Android Studio 0.2.3 on my mac, and these are the steps that made me view a maps fragment on a fresh hello world project template:

1) Click the SDK manager button in the toolbar in Android Studio.

2) Under 'Extras' locate 'Google play services' and install it.

3) in your build.gradle file in your src directory, add this line to dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
```

4) order and install your API-key following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

5) add the fragment to your layout xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

6) you should now be able to run your project on your device.

Comment: Please mind that the fragment must be `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` if you support older versions.

Comment: This finally worked for me under AS 0.3.1 though I had to restart AS before it did so.

Answer (score -1):

For those of you completely confused by everything going on with implementation of external libraries to gradle projects i have the easiest and most reliable solution.

Step by Step Guide: http://aetherstudios.net/pages/gradle.html

this might be a bit of work but it is the most reliable way i have found to get it done.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for contributing! This is not really a direct answer to the question that was posed. While it is often useful to include links to supporting material, you should give at least some direct answer or code sample here. Links sometimes go 404, and having an answer here helps things stay cohesive and relevant.

Comment: Although I agree this doesn't directly answer the question, the link provided is exactly what is needed and hardly merits a down vote. If you want to implement Google Maps in Android Studio using Gradle, this is the only way I have found that works.