# Android Studio 0.2 App that use Google Maps - Gradle modify

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm developing an App in Android studio. And I want use a Google maps API, but I can't use UI to configure project settings. I tried some different instruction to add maps, but it didn't work. I have to modify somehow build.gradle file? Can you tell me how? Does someone have experience with that?

Thanks for every advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on 0.2 it means that you already have Google Repository and Android Repository installed(from Android SDK: `terminal$ android sdk`).

One of them, has the Google Play services.
Here is a full build.gradle for your module:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Notice how(easily) the play services can be included.

Also gradle version is 0.5.+ so it can be auto updated!

**Also another VERY important thing**, that wasted me a lot of time is the minimum sdk version!
**It must be 8 or above,** since google play services aren't supported for lower versions!

Comment: If this doesnt work, you may want to read out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17663581/776345. It details the rest of the .gralde files, if you use libraries(sherlock?), etc! – Paschalis

Comment: Subquestion: How/where do you find out what version you should use? (3.1.36 for Play Services for example)

Comment: @thibaultd, I used them from this G+ post: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/4Yhpn6p9icf . Keep an eye on Android Developers on G+ for latest updates regarding gradle/studio/android dev in general!

Comment: Thanks! Not so handy but I haven't found anywhere else :)

Comment: @thibaultd [Gradle, please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) may be a bit more handy to you.