# Importing Eclipse project to Android Studio: Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm having some issues trying to import my project from Eclipse to Android studio. It is giving me errors such as `error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist` and `error: cannot find symbol class MapActivity`.

I've tried following the hundreds of posts about this problem and none seem to work. 
I tried putting this into my build.gradle: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'` and that doesn't work (I've also tried using the most current version as well). **Is this a problem with deprecation, because it doesn't seem to be complaining about SitesOverlay?**

I've tried changing my api key, which I don't think would give those errors.
I've also seen posts about modules and such but then I read from a few posts that that is not necessary. I have also made sure that I downloaded all the correct sdk stuff including all the extras etc.

A few of the many sites I have referenced already:

[Android Studio 0.2 App that use Google Maps - Gradle modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651096/android-studio-0-2-app-that-use-google-maps-gradle-modify)

[com.google.android.maps does not exist strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967549/com-google-android-maps-does-not-exist-strange-error)

[Package com.google.android.maps does not exist (IntelliJ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284022/package-com-google-android-maps-does-not-exist-intellij)

Comment: If you're having problems with the IDE not being able to resolve symbols, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols/21100896#21100896 and see how much it helps you

Comment: I'll try that but I have never been able to resolve this even after re-importing multiple times. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There's an issue in 0.4.2 where something bad is getting cached and re-import isn't helping. In my answer to that I have you blow away the .iml and .idea/ files and re-import. See if that helps, and if you're still stuck, revise your question with more details including your build.gradle files and more details on the exact errors you're seeing.

Comment: Okay, thank you. To be honest, I don't understand why this isn't a simple import like it is in eclipse.

Comment: Not implemented yet. We've got a ways to go before we declare it 1.0.

Comment: @BrandonLing check this out might be it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081598/import-google-play-services-library-in-android-studio/21086904#21086904

Answer (score 1):

My build.gradle file contains this:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+')
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30')
}
```

Below, My map activity imports these :

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

So I think it is just a cas of updating what you import to conform with the new map services.Specifically, you are using com.google.android.maps when you should be using com.google.android.gms.maps etc

Hope this helps.