# Cannot import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to create a new class in an Android project but keep getting the following error:

error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist

I have installed `Google Play Services` in the SDK manager. Any idea how to fix this?

*Android dev noob here*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596715/how-can-i-create-an-android-application-in-android-studio-that-uses-the-google-m

Comment: In step 5 I can only add a new module, I cannot import a module...

Comment: maybe something is outdated in studio menu. Try using new module. I haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: Please be more specific about the problems you're having. Your question is a little vague.

Comment: can i create my custom LatLng model class with the same variables?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your gradle file

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1"
```

Comment: can i create my custom LatLng model class with the same variables?

Comment: Changing to this version 10.0.1 solved the import issue, also after reverting back to 9.2.0 the problem was gone...

Answer (score 1):

For me, I started by discovering that upgrading my gradle was not going as planned, as I was importing from jcenter, which apparently only goes up to 2.3.  I modified my buildscript by adding google() to my build.gradle as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}
```

Next I found that it was importing com.google.android.gms multiple times, so when it told me that "compile" was obsolete, I had to change everything to either "implementation" or "api".  For the maps and location services I used "api", in order to avoid the duplication errors, and that fixed it for me without changing the play services number.

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
}
```