# android google map not load

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

My Problem is When App connect to Google Map APi V2 The Map Not load
It connected Without any error but map not loaded
The Zoom Buttom appears but.....

Please Help Me

If Do you have Any Simale Code For me to use it Please Give it to me
Thanks

It's manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.maps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission 
    android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAP_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAP_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.googel.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x0002000"
    android:required="true"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="[edited]"/>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


</application>
```

It's The Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

And It's MainActivity

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    }

}
```

Comment: it is probably a problem with the api Key, look at the answer below

Comment: I Try That Before But It's Not Work

Comment: Have you enabled de Google Maps Android API v2 on the google apis console?

Comment: Have you installed the GooglePlay-sevices in your device/emulator?

Comment: Yes I Enabled Google Maps Android API v2

Comment: Yes I Installed GooglePlay-sevices

Comment: I Tested This On A Real Device

Answer (score 0):

You sure the meta-data name is "**com.google.android.geo.API_KEY**" and not "**com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY**". Could you please check once.

Comment: I Try That Before But It's Not Work

Comment: Are you using a network which is behind a proxy connection? Can you open the Google maps application on the device?

Comment: Yes I Can Open the googel maps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use this in your manifest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_KEY_HERE" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You use **com.google.android.geo.API_KEY**, instead of **com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY**

UPDATE

Your MainActivity doesn't seem to load a map. A simple example looks like this:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            Location locationdefault = new Location("NewYork");
            locationdefault.setLatitude(41.145495);
            locationdefault.setLongitude(−73.994901);

}
```

Comment: Are you using Android Studio, or Eclipse?

Comment: You should consider using Android Studio, it is now the official IDE for Android. I think Eclipse can't recognize the 2 meta-data tags.

Comment: I Want But Android Studio Is Beta Version Yet

Comment: I'm using version 1.2. It gets updates very often and it's absolutely stable, not beta.It's easier than Eclipse.You can't use Google Play Services features with Eclipse anymore without dealing problems!

Comment: Ok Thanks.I didn't know the stable version is Available

Comment: I try that with Android Studio But it's Not Worked :-(

Comment: Well, many things could be wrong...I suggest you search around Stackoverflow.I had problems too, but I did it eventually!Just create a simple Google Maps Activity with Android Studio.Search around for a simple tutorial and you will make it! You could start here.. [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596715/how-can-i-create-an-android-application-in-android-studio-that-uses-the-google-m)