# Android: FragmentActivity within FragmentTabhost

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I do not know if this is best practice, but I am developing an application that requires me to have a number of tabs(Fragments) within a FragmentTabhost, which was fine until now, but the need has arisen to include a Google Map tab, within the FragmentTabhost.

Now, i have been doing some experimentation and it seems that a Google Maps V2 Fragment can only properly be used within a FragmentActivity, and not within a Fragment, as the application is laid out at the moment.

I have followed the Android V2 Quick Start Guide, https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw, where it only states that a FragmentActivity should be used, instead of an Activity, never that ONLY a FragmentActivity can be used.

Is there any way to add a FragmentActivity to a FragmentTabhost? If there is not, is it possible to have a Google Map V2 Fragment working properly within a Fragment?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Map worked in the Fragment after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure) post, i implemented the suggested answers, it seems i had an authorization issue.