# Authorization Failure in Google Maps Android V2

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, google-maps-android-api-2

When I try to debug my project I got this error using debug certificate

[image]

I already ensure that my package name and `SHA-1` corresponds to my api key

**Here's my AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:installLocation="auto" package="com.example">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 requires OpenGL ES v2 -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <!-- We need to be able to download map tiles and access Google Play Services-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 needs this permission so that it may check the connection state as it must download data -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Permission to receive remote notifications from Google Play Services -->
    <!-- Notice here that we have the package name of our application as a prefix on the permissions. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application android:label="map" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="map_key" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

**Here's my API KEY**

[image]

**Here's my SHA-1 certificate**

I got my SHA-1 using eclipse

[image]

By the way I'am using real device in debugging my project, c#, visual studio 2012 and xamarin.android. It only displays white screen with google logo and zoom in and out button. What's wrong with my debug certificate?

Comment: did you specify the same package name there

Comment: You shouldn't share your map key. Its dangerous.

Comment: yes I specify the same package name.

Comment: did u enabled the service u need in the Google maps?

Comment: Your SHA1 fingerprint 8c... doesnt match the certificate fingerprint you use ( error message). do you use the correct certificate?!. As long as you use IDE you should use the automatically created debug key.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure if u have not seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key is new ( has just been created in Google APIs Console ) it will take some time for it to be available to Google Maps.

Don't worry everything is declared OK, it just takes some time.

Edit : By what is written in the log looks like you have to add the fingerprint for your debug key store : D9595..

Just add a new line in Google APIs console with that fingerprint . Your debug keystore is found at C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore and the default password is : android