# How can get the GPS location in the service class

Tags: android

> How can get the GPS location in the service class I am trying with the
>   code below but its is showing the GPS location longitude and latitude
>   as 0.0 ,0.0
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>       import java.util.List;
>       import java.util.Timer;
>       import java.util.TimerTask;
>
> ```
> import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
> import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
> import org.json.JSONException;
> import org.json.JSONObject;
>
> import android.app.Service;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.content.SharedPreferences;
> import android.location.Geocoder;
> import android.os.AsyncTask;
> import android.os.IBinder;
> import android.text.format.Time;
> import android.util.Log;
>
> public class ServiceTest extends Service {
>
>   JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
>
>
>
>   GPSTracker gps;
>
>   Geocoder geocoder;
>
>
>   Double mylatitude, mylongitude;
>
>
>
>   String uid,code;
>
>   SharedPreferences sharpref_userdata;
>
>
>   @Override
>   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
>       return null;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void onCreate() {
>       super.onCreate();
>       mTimer = new Timer();
>       mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 8000, 6 * 1000);
>
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
>       try {
>
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>       return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
>   }
>
>   private Timer mTimer;
>
>   TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
>
>       @Override
>       public void run() {
>           Log.e("Log", "Running");
>           new empdats().execute();
>           Log.e("testing", "saving done");
>       }
>   };
>
>   public void onDestroy() {
>       try {
>           mTimer.cancel();
>           timerTask.cancel();
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>       Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.techtrainner");
>       intent.putExtra("yourvalue", "torestore");
>       sendBroadcast(intent);
>   }
>
>
>   class empdats extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
>       String status;
>       String message;
>       String data,time;
>
>
>
>       @Override
>       protected void onPreExecute() {
>           super.onPreExecute();
>
>           SharedPreferences prefuserdata = getSharedPreferences("userdata1", 0);
>           uid = prefuserdata.getString("empmob", "0");
>           code = prefuserdata.getString("empcode", "0");
>
>
>
>           Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
>           today.setToNow();
>           time = today.format("%k:%M:%S");
>
>           gps = new GPSTracker(ServiceTest.this);
>
>           // check if GPS enabled
>           if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
>
>               mylatitude = gps.getLatitude();
>               mylongitude = gps.getLongitude();
>
>               // \n is for new line
>
>           } else {
>               // can't get location
>               // GPS or Network is not enabled
>               // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
>               gps.showSettingsAlert();
>           }
>
>       }
>
>       protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
>           List<NameValuePair> userpramas = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>
>           userpramas.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid", code));
>           userpramas.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact", uid));
>           userpramas.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", mylongitude.toString()));
>           userpramas.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", mylatitude.toString()));
>           userpramas.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", time.toString()));
>           Log.e("testing", "msg to send==" + userpramas.toString());
>           JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(CommonClass.EMPJOIN_URL, "POST",
> ```
>
> userpramas);
>                 Log.e("testing", "json==" + json);
>
> ```
>           try {
>
>               status = json.getString("result");
>               data = json.getString("data");
>               Log.e("testing", "status==" + json);
>
>           } catch (JSONException e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }
>           return status;
>       }
>
>       @Override
>       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>           super.onPostExecute(result);
>
>
>
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> ```
>
> And my gps tracking code is

package com.my.emp;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location = null; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
     * app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * 
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
     * lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of tutorials out there just search them.

Comment: use right key u r soing something wrong in google map api key

Comment: the key is correct ive copy pasted from the google console but still not showing the map @NaveenTamrakar

Comment: if u create any key like andorid key or browser key and so on please uninstall apk tha rebuil apk

Comment: so you mean i should use the signed apk  not to run on targated device???.. ok let me try @NaveenTamrakar

Comment: have u know what is SHA1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Android API v2 Authorization failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure)

Comment: this is my sha1    44:E6:00:D5:DC:D9:C3:CD:E3:C9:0E:F3:21:81:31:B2:A9:51:BF:DF @NaveenTamrakar

Comment: so if is duplicate then shall i regenerate the key to get new 1 @SagarZala

Comment: @UditRoy is your apk a signed apk or unsigned apk?

Comment: you were right @NaveenTamrakar when i uninstalled and used the signed apk its working.... great

Answer (score 0):

first import **google-play-services_lib** to your work space then in your activity xml add following code

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/distance"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Add following code to your java file

```
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

and add following code in AndroidManifest.java file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="place your api key here" />
```