# Google Maps was working, Stopped after implementing OpenMap Weather service.Getting Authorization failure

Tags: android, google-maps, openmap

So I had google maps V2 implemented for about a year now, No issues with it. However after I implemented the weather service from open map , Authorization seems to fail .
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
This is a class that calls for OPEN WEATHER.I am wondering if the http call from here interferes with G.Maps sending request for authorization.

```
public class RemoteFetch {

private static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API =
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%s&units=metric";

public static JSONObject getJSON(Context context, String city){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(String.format(OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API, city));
        HttpURLConnection connection =
                (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key",
                context.getString(R.string.open_weather_maps_app_id));

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
        String tmp="";
        while((tmp=reader.readLine())!=null)
            json.append(tmp).append("\n");
        reader.close();

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());

        // This value will be 404 if the request was not
        // successful
        if(data.getInt("cod") != 200){
            return null;
        }

        return data;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

}
Those are related with maps

In Manifest :

```
<permission
        android:name="donate.cinek.wit.ie.ridetogether.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="donate.cinek.wit.ie.ridetogether.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIza.............................." />
```

Any other code as i said worked fine so not much point to post, will do if requested.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? It helps us figure out what might be wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your GoogleApi client key to your Singleton class (Do a initialization) which is accessible throughout the Application and it Should work fine.

I have done for me Like this by Making a `Singleton Class`

```
public class Model {

private static Model singleton = new Model( );
private GoogleApiClient _googleClient;


public void setGoogleClient(GoogleApiClient client){

    this._googleClient = client;


}

public GoogleApiClient getGoogleClient(){

    return this._googleClient;
}}
```

> **Note**: I have used this for Sign in with Google +

Comment: Kind of lost you, whats the procedure,as I said earlier this was working fine before

Comment: I have tested your solution but still getting the same error. any other ideas will be highly appropriated .thanks

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure

Comment: Hi , yeah i have followed the above post, completed all suggestions, or more accurately checked if everything was correct, Still have the same issue. Have installed play services, set up the manifest..Nothing.. just don't know what to do next to solve this issue

Comment: I have acquired a new api code from google and works fine, thanks for input

Comment: Hmmm congratulations... Happy coding...Make sure...Google keeps changing their api's...Regularly visit their Official Doc...Thanks