# Android google map api key authorization failed

Tags: android, google-maps

I have already confirm my google map api is right but still get this error. The google map api service is already installed too. I launch this project from other computers. The original one is written half year ago, so the google map api may expire and do not work. I request a new one from the link in the `google_map_api.xml` file when I launch the project. But it is still failed. I have already search the method in google but none of them fits in my project.

The error is showed below:

```
E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
    E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
    E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                               Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                               Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                API Key: AIzaSyAP40xIAML1UxDZgdPb6KKANBNvap01KGA
                                Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): CD:FD:78:5B:85:51:53:29:49:A0:91:77:D5:B5:38:47:6B:B5:A1:F1;com.example.administrator.locationandmaps
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps Android API v2 Authorization failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure)

Comment: Is API key AIzaSyAP40xIAML1UxDZgdPb6KKANBNvap01KGA created in your project and has required restriction: CD:FD:78:5B:85:51:53:29:49:A0:91:77:D5:B5:38:47:6B:B5:A1:F1;com.example.administrator.locationandmaps?

Comment: It is a duplicate but the original answer doesn't work